# Why the very same async/await function works somewhere and not elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, function, error-handling, async-await

Sometimes code makes you crazy because you know the answer must be simple.

Consider this **working** function (I use `firestore`) :

```
async function getHousing(id) {
  const housing = await db
    .collection('HOUSINGS')
    .doc(id)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) logger.debug('No such housing')
      return doc.data()
    })
    .catch(e => {
      logger.error(e)
      return
    })
  return housing
}

module.exports.getHousing = getHousing
```

When I use it somewhere, `requiring` it accordingly, it **works like a charme**, aka no error:

```
const { getHousing } = require('../models/housing')

async function getHousings(user) {

  ...

  for (let house of allowedHousings) {
    let housing = await getHousing(id)    
  }

  ...

  return someStuff
}
```

However, when I'm using it somewhere else, requiring the very same way, I got an error: **`error: getHousing is not a function`**

```
const { getHousing } = require('../models/housing')

async function saveProp(data) {
  try {
    await db
      .collection('PROPS')
      .doc(data.ID.PROP)
      .set(data)

    // data.ID.HOUSING is the correct ID
    const housing = await getHousing(data.ID.HOUSING)

    return housing
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e)
  }
}
```

I really can't see why. Do you have any clue? Thanks

EDIT: In fact, when I switch for another async function working also somewhere (`saveHousing()`), it doesn't work any more into `saveProp()` fn... Weird, but doesn't help me debug this...

Comment: If the path were wrong, the error would be `Error: Cannot find module`

Comment: The path is indeed correct...(This bug makes me crazy!). I've just edited my question to add a weird evidence...

Comment: Why do you use both **await** and **then** in one line? Have you tried something like this: `const docHousing = await db.collection('HOUSINGS').doc(id).get();` and then just `return docHousing.data();`. Of course wrap this function in **try catch**. And before `return` check for existence of docHousing and return something (like empty object)

Comment: @D.Kurapin You're right, thx (I will update my code), but the bug remains...

Comment: Is it in the same project? Otherwise different environments (node versions) could cause the problem.

Comment: @PutziSan : very same project and env.

Comment: also if there is only one function inside I would prefer to write it like this: `exports.getHousing = async function().....`. In this case you don't need **module.exports**

Answer (score 0):

After some times trying to debug... I found the answer, the functions work perfectly but there was a kind of **circular dependencie** with all my `require()`.

After having moved a `const { deleteProp } = require('../models/prop')` **inside** a function and not at the top of the file, it works.